# Tool to synthesize functions

Tags: functions, curves, constraints

Often I need functions with some properties I can describe.

I'm able to plot on paper a function working for my purpose, but I need a formal way to express it. I'm bad at it, and finding a working formula takes me a considerable amount of efforts.

Are there any tools that can aid me in finding a formula, as simple as possible, satisfying my constraints?

I considered using splines and similar interpolation tools, but they have many drawbacks: they're usually not defined in all of $\mathbb R$; can't easily express local minimums and maximums, how fast the function grows in certain intervals or other similar constraints; their expression is also way *uglier* and with a lot more terms than it could be.

---

For instance, right now I was looking for a function $f$ such that:

- $f(0)=0$
- $f(35)=0$
- $f(20)=1$ is the maximum
- to the left, it diverges slowly (e.g. sub-linearly) to $-\infty$
- to the right, it diverges quickly (e.g. linearly or super-linearly) to $-\infty$
- it's monotonic in both the intervals $(-\infty, 20]$ and $[20, \infty)$
- it should be smooth (e.g. continuous first derivative)

In my experience these classes of functions usually have many clean solutions, expressed with nice simple formulas... But how can I find one without spending half an hour going crazy on Wolfram Αlpha?

Comment: find a polynomial with those roots, and edit it ?

Comment: Edit it how? Polynomials have similar issues as splines. I'm unable to edit a polynomial to make it converge at Infinity or to make the function monotonic in a given interval etc.

Comment: Okay it was just an idea. I'm not advanced.

Comment: I'm worse, trust me :) I've just been trying to play with interpolations for a bit though, but got no luck.

Comment: Nope, I've tried Geometrizing Goldbach ...

Comment: You can always use a piecewise function.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have to do when I can't find better solutions. A piecewise function a bit uglier to express and less smooth, but I can live with it. It's a pity that there's no tool to derive a nice clean function, but well...

Comment: take the derivative ?

Comment: Years ago I used to do a lot of curve fitting. I used a program called Table Curve 2D. See here: http://www.sigmaplot.co.uk/products/tablecurve2d/tablecurve2d.php.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I checked it out. The idea is basically what I'm looking for, but results aren't great. It couldn't get nice equations even for very simple curves. It seems to support only few elementary functions without even composing them: it basically offers some *extended* polynomials (e.g. summed to trivial power/exponential functions).